# Change between activities does not work

Tags: java, android, sdk

I'm trying to change between activities in my Android app (2.1-update1), but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

The only thing that happens when I debug the app is that it stops on this part of the code in Instrumentation.java:

```
public void waitForIdle() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (!mIdle) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Eclipse says that it is in Thread 1 on

> Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1537. If I
>   resume the app, the next stop is in ZygoteInit.java trying to run
>   Throwable cause = ex.getCause(); ... Eclipse says
>   ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 864.

Here is the source code:
**HappyHomes.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HappyHomes extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ProgressDialog laddRuta = ProgressDialog.show(HappyHomes.this, "",
                        "Loggar in, vänligen vänta...", true);

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Kategorier.class);
                myIntent.
                        startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Kategorier.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Kategorier extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kategorier);
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you show the output of the logcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that `Kategorier` is registered in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Change `myIntent.startActivity(myIntent);` to `HappyHomes.this.startActivity(myIntent);`

Answer (score 1):

There is no any startActivity() method in Intent class . you must be doing wrong. 
just write startActivity(myIntent)

Answer (score 0):

All the Services, Broadcast Receivers and Activites must be declared in manifest file.